How to reset password without email using token in Laravel?
I'm trying to implement a password reset functionality in my Laravel application without requiring the email address, using only the reset token. I encountered an issue because the Password::tokenExists method requires both the token and user data, but there's no straightforward way to get user data with only the token.
Here's my current approach:
Store the reset token in the remember_token column of the users table.
Retrieve the user based on the remember_token.
Validate the token.
Reset the password if the token is valid.
Here's my implementation:
public function resetPassword(Request $request) {
    try {
        $request->validate([
            'token' => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:8'
        ]);

        $user = User::where('remember_token', $request->token)->first();

        // Validate the token
        if (!$user || !Password::tokenExists($user, $request->token)) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => false,
                'message' => 'Invalid or expired token.',
            ], 400);
        }

        // Reset the password
        $user->password = Hash::make($request->password);
        $user->remember_token = null;
        $user->save();

        // Remove the reset token after successful password reset
        Password::deleteToken($user);

        return response()->json([
            'status' => true,
            'message' => 'Password has been reset successfully.',
        ]);

    } catch (ValidationException $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => false,
            'message' => $e->getMessage(),
            'errors' => $e->errors(),
        ], 422);

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => false,
            'message' => $e->getMessage(),
        ], $e->getCode() ?: 500);
    }
}

My questions are:

Is storing the reset token in the remember_token column and retrieving the user based on this token a good approach?
Are there any better or more secure methods to achieve password reset functionality without requiring the email address?

Any suggestions or improvements would be greatly appreciated!

why would someone have their token but not their email?

Still calling Password::tokenExists is probably pointless at that point anyway. That is supposed to check, if for the given user, the token exists in the database, right? Well if that wasn't the case, you would not have been able to fetch the user, based on the passed token, in the first place ...

Reset tokens in the database is supposed to be hashed and shall be used with email so hashes can be matched against reset tokens and email. This also helps in better security as reset token api may get brute force however you can use DB::table('password_reset_tokens')->where('token', $token)->first() //unsafe

In the real world, if I get something like this, the first thing that comes to mind is very SUS

The reset token is sent to the user's email. When they click the link, it directs them to a reset page where they only enter their new password and confirm it, without asking for their email again. This simplifies the user experience. That's why we have the token but not the email. I'm looking for a better or more secure way to implement this in Laravel.

Reply to CBroe: Thanks for your input, CBroe. However, just because a token exists in the users table doesn't mean it's still valid. The Password::tokenExists method handles more than just the existence check; it also validates the token's expiry and other constraints. That's why I still call Password::tokenExists even after fetching the user based on the token.
